# Extract the directory path containing the file with matching string

Tags: files, grep, find, directory

I have multiple subdirectories at multiple levels containing a file results.out

```
./dir1/results.out
./dir2/dir21/results.out
./dir3/dir31/dir311/results.out
```

Now I need to search for `string1` in `results.out` and extract the directory path of those `results.out` that contain the `string1`, since I need to move these sub-directories to another location. For example, I can get the file path using the following code

```
for i in $(find . -type f -name "results.out);
do
grep -l "string1" $i
done
```

How to modify the above code to get only the directory path?

Answer (score 5):

If you have GNU `find`, you can print the path using the `%h` format specifier

```
    %h     Leading directories of file's name (all but the last ele‐
           ment).  If the file name contains no slashes (since it is
           in  the  current  directory)  the %h specifier expands to
           ".".
```

So for example you could do

```
find . -name 'results.out' -exec grep -q 'string1' {} \; -printf '%h\n'
```

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl ./**/results.out(.e_'grep -q string $REPLY'_:h)
```

this searches recursively for regular files (`.`) named `results.out`, runs  `grep -q ...` on each of them and if that `e`valuates *true* it prints only the `h`ead of the path (the path without the last element).

---

Another way with `find` and `sh`, using `${parameter%/*}` expansion to extract the head:

```
find . -type f -name results.out -exec grep -q string {} \; \
-exec sh -c 'printf %s\\n "${1%/*}"' bang {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
for i in $(find . -type f -name "results.out);
do
grep -l "string1" $i ; exitcode=${?}
if [ ${exitcode} -eq 0 ]  # string1 is found in file $i
then
   path=${i%/*}
   echo ${path}
fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

On a GNU system:

```
 find . -depth -type f -name results.out -exec grep -lZ string1 {} + |
   xargs -r0 dirname -z |
   xargs -r0 mv -t /dest/dir
```

Or:

```
 find . -depth -type f -name results.out -exec grep -lZ string1 {} + |
   LC_ALL=C sed -z 's|/[^/]*$||' |
   xargs -r0 mv -t /dest/dir
```

The `-depth` is so that if both `./A/results.out` and `./A/B/results.out` match, `./A/B` is moved to `/dest/dir/B` before `./A` is moved to `/dest/dir/A`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understood correctly you want to do just that:

```
find . -type f -name "results.out" -exec grep -l "string1" {} \; | xargs dirname
```

First part gets matching filenames, then xargs passes those as an argument to dirname program which 'strips' filelame from path

Comment: Even though `dirname` is available in any recent distribution of Linux, it is still an external command and might not be available on minimally installed systems. Just a word of caution.

Comment: Not all `dirname` implementations accept more than  one argument. (POSIX `dirname` specification doesn't). As usual with `xargs`, you'll also have issues with file paths containing blanks or quotes or backslash. You may as well use `\;` instead of `+` here to avoid having to run one `grep` per file.