# Find file and get only directory path

Tags: bash, find

I am attempting to find files and then `grep` expression for some string in the files, then only get back the full directory path the files are found in.

```
find `pwd` -iname '*.py' -type f -exec bash -c "grep -l 'nn'; sed 's[\/](.*)*[\/]/d' {}" \;
```

However, the `sed` expression will have the terminal hang, rather than recursively print out the files and removing the file from the directory path.

I can partially achieve this with:

```
find `pwd` -iname 'nn*' -type d
```

However, this expects the directory name to have `nn` and not for `nn` inside the file.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate [Extract the directory path of the file with matching string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/297226)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the path to include the filename:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
grep -l 'nn' **/*.py | xargs realpath
```

To only get the directory the matched file is located in:

````bash
```bash
shopt -s globstar
grep -l 'nn' **/*.py | xargs realpath | xargs dirname
````

To remove duplicate directory names:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
grep -l 'nn' **/*.py | xargs realpath | xargs dirname | sort -u
```

If you have very many `.py` files you may get 'Argument list too long' error.

In that case use find as:

```bash
find `pwd` -iname '*.py' | xargs grep -l 'nn' | xargs dirname | sort -u
```

All the above assumes directories without newlines in the paths. If newlines may be present in the paths, add a comment and I will add some more solutions.

Comment: So I have a question, when I use: ```find `pwd` -iname '*.py' -type f -exec bash -c "grep -l 'nn' {}; dirname {}; sort -u {}" \;``` then final argument `sort -u` will print out the content also, how would I get it to print out only the unique files with this approach?

Comment: @Workingdollar: I think it should be ```find `pwd` -iname '*.py' -type f -exec bash -c "grep -l 'nn' {} " \; | xargs dirname | sort -u``` or ```find `pwd` -iname '*.py' -type f -exec bash -c "grep -l 'nn' {} | xargs dirname 2> /dev/null" \; | sort -u```, i.e. to have the `sort` after the `find` command. (it will hang for a bit since `sort` needs the entire output before printing anyting).